# I need to get the largest total overall and display the staffs name that relates to it

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

```
Select FirstName + ' ' + LastName 'StaffName' from Staff
Where (Select Month(Date) from job) = Month(GetDate())
Group by FirstName + ' ' + LastName
Having (Select Total from Job) = (Select Max(Total) from Job group by Total)
```

I need to display the staffs name who has made the largest sale each month but I can only get it to give me the maximum sale of each individual not overall. Im still a beginner and have been trying lots of different things trying to fix such as having everything in the Where clause or instead using an Inner Join but at this point I can't figure it out.

```
    Create Table Staff
(
StaffID int not null
constraint pk_Staff primary key clustered,
FirstName varchar (50) not null,
LastName varchar (50) not null,
TrainingCredits smallint not null,
StaffTypeCode int not null
constraint fk_StaffToStaffType references StaffType(StaffTypeCode),
Phone varchar(14) not null
constraint ck_StaffPhone check (Phone like '([0-9][0-9][0-9]) [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
)

Create Table Job
(
JobNumber int identity (1,1) not null
constraint pk_Job primary key clustered,
Date datetime not null,
Address varchar(100) not null,
City varchar (50) not null,
Province char(2) not null
constraint ck_Province check (Province like '[a-z][a-z]'),
PostalCode char(7) not null
constraint ck_PostalCode check (PostalCode like '[a-z][0-9][a-z] [0-9][a-z][0-9]'),
SubTotal money not null,
GST money not null,
Total money not null,
StaffID int not null
constraint fk_JobToStaff references Staff(StaffID),
ClientID int not null
constraint fk_JobToClient references Client(ClientID),
constraint ck_SubTotalandTotal check (Total > Subtotal)
)
```

Comment: You will need to link your job table and your staff table

Comment: Can you post the table structures?

Comment: Please add table information. Its not clear to answer

Comment: Do You mean you need to get the details for the staff who has the maximum SubTotal for each month? is that correct ?

Comment: Yup thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName 'StaffName', maxPerMonth.Month, maxPerMonth.max 
FROM Staff s INNER JOIN Job j ON s.StaffID = j.StaffID
             INNER JOIN (SELECT Month(Date) AS Month, MAX(Total) max
                          FROM Job
                          GROUP BY Month(Date)
                         ) maxPerMonth ON Month(j.Date) = maxPerMonth.Month AND
                                          j.Total = maxPerMonth.max
```

The subquery groups by Month and selects the maximum total, as far as I understand, this is what you want. 
Because both the Date and the MAX(total) are contained in this table, you can join these Value against the table itself, to get the staffID where these values fit. 
To get the Name of the staff you only have to join the Staff table on it's primary key.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (Staff.FirstName +SPACE(1)+ Staff.LastName) AS 'StaffName' ,
       MAX(Total) AS TOTAL 
  FROM Staff INNER JOIN job 
     ON(Staff.StaffID=job.StaffID) 
   GROUP BY MONTH(JOB.Date),(Staff.FirstName +SPACE(1)+ Staff.LastName)
```